# Flex/Bison start condition

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

How to enable a start condition at the beginning of a rule and disable it at the end ? I have to ignore whitespace with some bison rules only. 
How to ignore whitespace inside nested brackets.

```
define_directive:
    DEFINE '(' class_name ')'{ ... }
;
```

I'm trying to write a parser for this sample code with some more rules.

```
@/*
  * @Template Family
  * @Description sample script template for Mate Programming language
  * (multi-line comment)
  */

@namespace(sample)

@require(String fatherName)
@require(String motherName)
@require(Array childrenNames)
@define(Family : Template) @// end of header anything can go in body section below (comment)

Family Description
==================

    Father's Name: @(fatherName)
    Mother's Name: @(motherName)
    Number of child: @(childrenNamesCount,0) @// valuation operator is null safe (comment)

    List of children's names
    ------------------------
    @foreach(childName:childrenNames)
        > @(childName)
    @empty
        > there is no child name to display.
    @end

    @@(varName) @// this should not be interpreted because escaped with @ (comment)
```

Lexer and parser partially implemented. My problem is how to deal with whitespace inside statement keywords like @foreach, @require.
Whitespaces should be ignored for these.

desired sample output

```
Family Description
==================

    Father's Name: Mira
    Mother's Name: James
    Number of child: 0

    List of children's names
    ------------------------

        > there is no child name to display.

    @@(varName)
```

bison file content

```
command:
    fileword
    | valuation
    | alternative
    | loop
    | command_directive
;
fileword: 
    tokenword { scriptlangy_echo(yytext,"fileword.tokenword"); }
    | MAGICESC { scriptlangy_echo("@","fileword.MAGICESC"); }
;
tokenword:
    IDENTIFIER | NUMBER | STRING_LITERAL | WHITESPACE
    | INC_OP | DEC_OP | AND_OP | OR_OP | LE_OP | GE_OP | EQ_OP | NE_OP | L_OP | G_OP
    | ';' | ',' | ':' | '=' | ']' | '.' | '&' | '[' | '!' | '~' | '-' | '+' | '*' | '/' | '%' | '^' | '|' | ')' | '}' | '?' | '{' | '('
;
valuation:
    '@' '(' expression ')' {
        fprintf(yyout, "<val>");
    }
    | '@' '(' expression ',' default_value ')' {
        fprintf(yyout, "<val>");
    }
;
loop:
    for_loop
    | foreach_loop
    | while_loop
;
while_loop:
    WHILE '(' expression ')' end_block
    | WHILE '(' expression ')' commands end_block
;
for_loop:
    FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement expression')' end_block
    | FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement expression')' commands end_block
;
foreach_loop:
    foreach_block end_block
    | foreach_block empty_block end_block
;
foreach_block:
    FOREACH '(' IDENTIFIER ')'
    | FOREACH '(' IDENTIFIER ':' expression')' commands
;
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  Start conditions are an aspect of the lexer definition, which is the exclusive domain of `flex`.  If you are using only `bison` rules to achieve some purpose (*any* purpose) then the implementation cannot involve start conditions.  Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: Furthermore, Bison generates LALR(1) parsers, which use (up to) one token of lookahead.  Generally speaking, then, the parser cannot have an effect on the lexer's behavior that ends with the last token of a single rule, because it doesn't know when it has parsed the last token of a rule until it sees the *next* token, which therefore needs already to have been scanned.  And the parser even more so cannot affect the scanner for the *first* token of a rule, since it cannot know until it sees that token what rule it may be using.

Comment: **@foreach(childName:childrenNames)** work fine but I'm not able to handle it with whitespace inside brackets

Comment: You have not presented the rules you use to parse a `@foreach` directive.  If the problem is a specific one involving particular rules, then our expectation is that you will present a representative [mcve] on which we can base an answer.

Comment: That's it `foreach_block:
    FOREACH '(' IDENTIFIER ')'
    | FOREACH '(' IDENTIFIER ':' expression')' commands
;`

Comment: You seem not to be familiar with our usage of the term [mcve], because what you've presented still isn't one.  There is on one hand a bunch of extraneous stuff -- so it's nowhere near minimal -- and on the other hand it is incomplete, so also not verifiable. I have no way to determine the reason for your shift / reduce conflicts or how to fix them.  I'm inclined to guess that it is related to the productions for `expression`, and I'm suspicious of the appearance of `WHITESPACE` in the production for `tokenword`, but there's nothing concrete I can say.

Comment: Really sorry for that Sir. Here are links to complete flex and bison files (https://github.com/xolens/mate/blob/master/scriptlang/scriptlang.l) and (https://github.com/xolens/mate/blob/master/scriptlang/scriptlang.y)

Comment: I'm trying to allow use of whitespace inside interpretable blocks like `@foreach(...)`

Comment: Really thankful for you help. I'm going to try some more again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part of your question seems to be this:

> I have to ignore whitespace with some bison rules only. How to ignore
>   whitespace inside nested brackets.

As I remarked in comments, your implementation idea of somehow doing this by having your parser rules manipulate scanner start conditions is pretty much a non-starter.  Forget about that.

Since evidently your scanner *does not*, in general, ignore whitespace, it must emit tokens that represent whitespace, or perhaps tokens that represent something else plus whitespace (ugly).  If it emits whitespace tokens then the thing to do is simply to account for them in your grammar rules.  This is completely possible.  In fact, you can build a parser for any context-free language on top of a scanner that just returns every character as its own token.  The scanner / parser dichotomy is a functional and conceptual convenience, not a necessity.

For example, then, suppose we want to be able to parse numeric array literals, formed as a nonempty, comma-delimited list of decimal numbers enclosed in curly braces, with optional whitespace around commas and inside the braces.  Suppose further that we have these terminal symbols to work with:

```
OPEN  // open brace
CLOSE // close brace
NUM   // maximal sequence of one or more decimal digits
COMMA // a comma
WS    // a maximal run of whitespace
```

We might then write these rules:

```
array: array_start array_elements CLOSE;

array_start: OPEN
    | OPEN WS
  ;

array_elements: array_element
    | array_elements array_separator array_element
  ;

array_element: NUM
    | NUM WS
  ;

array_separator: COMMA
    | COMMA WS
  ;
```

There are, of course, many other ways to set up the details, but, generally speaking, *this* is how you handle whitespace with parser rules: not by ignoring it, but by *accepting* it.

Comment: I tried do to like this but I got several reduce/shift conflicts, because of the fact that in body section (after @define directive) I use Whitespace token.

Comment: And my example does not have any such conflicts, @Cedric.  Since you have not presented the problematic rules, the best I can do is offer a good example of how to do this general sort of thing.  I can only hope that you will use it as inspiration for fixing your own rules.  Note, too, that although you generally can and should avoid shift/reduce conflicts, they do not prevent parser generation, and if they are few then the generated parser is often satisfactory.

Comment: Thank for you help, I tried something like that but I got shift/reduce error because whitespace should be interpreted here `@@foreach( anaything )` because escaped with **@** but not in `@foreach(...)`

Comment: I respectfully disagree with this advice. In embedded languages, it is very common to need to change lexical context during the parse, and it can be done wirh bison/flex. Although it's true that lookahead complicates the situation, it can be dealt with.

Comment: It works now, I tried again by changing some tokens. I include whitespace whiting separation tokens. Great thanks

Comment: Are you in fact disagreeing with my *advice*, @rici, or with some of my comments on the OP's question?  If indeed you hold that teaching the parser where to accept whitespace is an inferior solution, then I'm curious as to why you say so.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: with your advice. The comments are spot-on. I was going to write up an answer explaining my disagreement, and I suppose I should even though yours was accepted. The summary: First, the problem is not ignoring spaces in expressions. The problem is using an expression tokeniser to tokenise unparsed text. It would be like tokenising quoted strings using a full C tokeniser instead of just recognising them as quoted strings. Second, there is a reason why whitespace is typically ignored in grammars; indeed, ignoring whitespace is an important motivation for the lexer/parser...

Comment: ...dichotomy. It is possible to add whitespace into a grammar; indeed, it is possible to write scannerless parsers and some people like them. But I don't, because the incorporation of whitespace makes the grammar much less readable and it often makes the grammar not LR(1).

Comment: In short, OP's problem would better be solved by using a separate lexical context for unparsed text which doesn't attempt to tokenise other than for the sigils indicating embedded parsed text. The parser must then find a way to communicate to the lexer that the embedded parsed text is terminated, but that is easy to do by putting the start condition transition into a MRA *before* the terminating close parenthesis.